# How to apply condition in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to apply conditions in my query, I want to change one column's value to another column on a condition. Please see my query and exactly that I want...

```
  select user_pro.User_No, user_pro.Fist_Name, user_pro.Last_Name, user_pro.Designation, user_pro.Profile, user_pro.ProfileDP, user_fndrqt.Frnd_SNo, user_fndrqt.Rqst_Sender, user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver, user_fndrqt.Rqst_Status from user_pro INNER JOIN user_fndrqt ON user_pro.User_No = user_fndrqt.Rqst_Sender WHERE user_fndrqt.Rqst_Status='1' AND user_fndrqt.Rqst_Sender='$user_id' OR user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id' ORDER BY Frnd_SNo DESC
```

In this query user_pro table contains user details and user_fndrqt contains friend request status details $user_id contains user's logined ID. Now Here I want that if user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id' then user_fndrqt.Rqst_Sender value move to user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver coloumn.

Answer (score 0):

then use an IF in your select for column user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver

```
IF(user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver='$user_id, user_fndrqt.Rqst_Sender,
           user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver) as user_fndrqt.Rqst_Receiver
```